# When defining a prototype of an overloaded C++ function template, is it legal to use its name to refer to previous definitions?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Let's say we want to overload a function template *f*, but only if a similar overload is not declared yet:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T); // main prototype

struct A {};
struct B {}; 

//we want to declare B f(A), but only if something like A f(A) hasn't been declared
//we can try to check the type of expression f(A) before defining it
//and disable overload via enable_if
template<typename T = void>   //it has to be a template to use enable_if
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<void, decltype(T(), (f)(A{}))>, B> f(A);
// decltype expression depends on T, but always evaluates to the type of (f)(A{})
// parenthesis are used to disable ADL, so only preceding definitions are visible
```

The code is accepted by Clang, kind of works on GCC (See 
 https://godbolt.org/g/ZGfbDW), and causes compiler error 'recursive type or function dependency context too complex' on Visual C++ 15.5.

My question is: is this a legal declaration according to the C++ standard or does it involve undefined behavior?

Comment: Is getting `B` as a type of `a` at godbolt link code a desired behavior?

Comment: @VTT yes, in the linked code B f (A) is declared first, so all the following declarations will be disabled.

Comment: I will edit the question with link that declares A f (A) first, to avoid confusion

Comment: @VTT I am not sure it's the same template. Clang thinks it is not, at least. At the point of the second declaration, the first A f(A) is already declared, that changes the meaning of (f)(A{}), so repeating declaration declares different template.

Comment: Actually I think that VS fails because it lacks proper support for two-phase name lookup. It tries to take all the templates into account at the same time (not only those previously declared) and fails.

Comment: @VTT You're right. After I enabled two-phase name lookup via /permissive- it started to compile on Visual C++. But repeated definition causes an error.

Comment: I think you are on the border line of  *functionaly equivalent template*, so your code is probably ill-formed. See [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf) / 17.6.6.1 [temp.over.link]. I am not sure of that, but maybe you could check it.

Comment: @Oliv I guess you mean specifically the repeated declaration. And I agree that I almost on the border of _functionally equivalent template_, but as far as I can see I do not cross it. I might be wrong but  _f_ in _(f)(A{})_ is not a dependent name and it means different things during first and second declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a legal declaration based simply on there not really being any reason for it to not be.

Couple things worth pointing out. First, we have two uses of `f` here, and they are different:

```
template<typename T = void>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<void, decltype(T(), (f)(A{}))>, B> f(A);
//                                                  ^^^           ^^^
//                                                   #1            #2
```

We are declaring the name `f` in `#2`, but it is not in scope for its usage in `#1`<sup>†</sup> - its point of declaration is after the complete declarator, which includes that `enable_if_t` block. So there's no recursion here. If VS has a problem with it, I suspect it might be related to their general issues around name lookup in templates.

Second, these aren't functionally equivalent templates - the main prototype takes an argument whose type is the template parameter, and this one takes an `A`. The point of functional equivalency is to match up declarations to definitions in a way that doesn't require token-by-token copies - but our two `f` function templates in this example are totally different.

I don't see a reason for this to be ill-formed. Eyebrow-raising, yes. Ill-formed, no.

---

<sup>†</sup>This leads to a fairly common error when trying to declare a recursive function template whose return type depends on itself. e.g.:

```
template <size_t V>
using size_ = std::integral_constant<size_t, V>; 

constexpr size_<0> count() { return {}; }

template <typename T, typename... Ts> 
constexpr auto count(T, Ts... ts)
    -> size_<decltype(count(ts...))::value + 1> { return {}; }

int main() {
    static_assert(count() == 0);      // ok
    static_assert(count(1) == 1);     // ok
    static_assert(count(1, 2) == 2);  // error: no matching function to call
}
```

Comment: I believe comment regarding functionally equivalent templates was regarding repeated declaration in godbolt link. Improved version here: https://godbolt.org/g/wM8CKo

Here we have two templates with identical declarations, which may be thought as equivalent.

Comment: @ГригорийШуренков I'm not sure what I'm supposed to take away from this comment?

Comment: Oh, I like your answer , I was just trying to explain how the idea of functionally equivalent templates came up.

Comment: @Barry I just asked a question on the subject just of template functional equivalence. [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678870/template-equivalence-or-template-functional-equivalence). I admit that this part of the standard confuse me. I hope you can give an answer and explanation.