# Template equivalence or template functional equivalence?

Tags: c++, templates

In the C++ standard [temp.over.link], it is explained that the determination of function template equivalence should not involve "heroic efforts" of the compiler.

As an example, the C++ standard propose this:

```
// guaranteed to be the same
template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
// guaranteed to be different
template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+11>);
// ill-formed, no diagnostic required
template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+1+2+3+4>);
```

Is this rule also applies to cases involving meta programming, as in the example below?

```
template<class T>
struct t_{
   using type = T;
   };
//ill-formed or different?
template<class T> T f(T);
template<class T> typename t_<T>::type f(T);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the simple case:

```
template <typename T> using id = T;

template<class T> T f(T);
template<class T> id<T> f(T);
```

This to me is clearly ill-formed, no diagnostic required, per [the relevant rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.over.link#6). The two declarations are functionally equivalent, but not in a way that's simply renaming template parameters (and there aren't any dependent names to consider).

---

With the more complicated case:

```
template <typename T> struct id_t { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using id = typename id_t<T>::type;

template<class T> T f(T);
template<class T> id<T> f(T);
```

I think this is probably *not* ill-formed, because they aren't truly functionally equivalent. There could be specializations of `id_t` such that these two declarations are actually different - so these are actually different declarations.

Comment: Haha, clang and gcc crash because of "id_t" being a typdef (need to include iostream)

Comment: Good point there at the end about it being possible to have actually different declarations. In this scenario, is it even possible to construct such a specialization such that a resulting function call attempt is not ambiguous, though?

Comment: @AndyG So this is it, the question I posted in my last comment of your answer, `T` and `id<T>` are not equivalent because `id<T>` can be specialized. He is realy strong!!

Comment: The first example looks like a redeclaration to me - though it's really another "how transparent are alias templates?" issue (see CWG 1979 and issues linked therein). Note that the token-identity-based "equivalent" rule is for expressions only.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in this scenario they are considered different:

```
template<class T>
struct t_{
   using type = T;
   };
//ill-formed or different?
template<class T> T f(T);
template<class T> typename t_<T>::type f(T);
```

Because [temp.over.link] says (**emphasis mine**)

> For determining whether two
>   dependent names  are equivalent, **only the name itself is considered, not the result of name lookup in
>   the context of the template**.

Since `T` and `typename t_<T>::type` differ in naming, the compiler will accept these template declarations.

Now, you couldn't actually *call* either of them because the resulting template instantiations are *functionally equivalent*, resulting in ambiguity. This sort of program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required* (See [@Barry's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47679533/27678)).

[MSVC 19.00.23506](http://rextester.com/LKTII28811), [clang 6.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/frpEr6zTQujIEZFJ), and [gcc 8.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WMrL5wP1VHxN33Qb) all appear to agree with me on this (none of them issue a diagnostic).

Note that the compiler allows these templates to be declared, so long as they aren't called, whereas something like this won't compile even if the templates are not instantiated:

```
template<class U> typename t_<U>::type f(U){return {};}
template<class T> typename t_<T>::type f(T){return {};}
```

---

* "If a program contains declarations of function
templates that are functionally equivalent but not equivalent, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic
required."

Comment: I asked this question because of this [tricky case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668769/when-defining-a-prototype-of-an-overloaded-c-function-template-is-it-legal-to?noredirect=1#comment82308210_47668769). I had seen compilers all agree, but because of the "no diagnostic required", I was doubting. But I am still doubting, the paragraph you cite is about *equivalence*, but this not exclude them from being *functionaly equivalent*.

Comment: @Oliv: If my understanding is correct, we must distinguish between "equivalent" and "functionally equivalent". It's possible to be functionally equivalent, but not equivalent, which is ill-formed.

Comment: So to prove "is not ill-formed", you must proove that these declarations "are not equivalent" (what you have done), and you also must proove that they "are not functionnaly equivalent". You have not done the last demonstration, this may seem obvious for you, but this is exactly my problem: why `t_<T>::type` and `T` are not functionnaly equivalent, they result in the same type??

Comment: It's precisely because `t_<T>::type` is always `T` that makes them functionally equivalent. You could theoretically specialize `t_` to create a declaration that is not functionally equivalent, however.

Comment: "functionally equivalent" is a relationship between two *function templates*, not two *function template specializations*. The ambiguity between the two specializations causes overload resolution to fail, but that's plain ill-formed, not NDR.